# Deprecated version of DFP (v201508)

Tags: 7, advertising

We are getting emails from google about the latest version of Double-click for Publishers' (dpf) API.

Currently our site appears to still be using a deprecated version (v201508) and need to update to v201608 by November 30.
https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/deprecation

Is this dfp api change is going to affect the dfp module?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the DFP module doesn't load API version specific files and so unless you are using additional custom JS or loading the DFP JS files directly from your site (instead of pulling them from Google), there is no reason the API change should effect the module itself.